# Save how long took for a task to be completed (in days)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am building a project management sheet. How can I change the cell value like:

if(doing) = calculate days passed till today
if(done) = stop updating, saving the "LastToday-StartDay)

Till now it's like this:
=IF(AND(G26="Doing"; NOT(H27="")); TODAY()-H27; "")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column I put this in row 2 and copy down:

```
=iferror(if(H2<>"",today()-H2,""))
```

In column J put this in row 2 and copy down:

```
=iferror(if(G2="Done",H2+I2,""))
```

In the script editor copy and paste this:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//get sheet by name
var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();//get 
column G value
var editedCol = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();//get 
edited column number
var editRow=event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();//get edited row
if(editedCol==7 && editedCell=="Done"){//if column is G and G="Done"
 var cpy=s.getRange(editRow,9 ,1, 2).getDisplayValues()//get values (not 
formulas) of I and J 
 var cpyVal=s.getRange(editRow,9 ,1, 2).setValues(cpy)// overwrite foemulas 
with values
}}
```

If colummn G is edited and it;s value is "Done" the display value is copied from column I and overwrites the formula. The completion date (the date when done was set) is set in J. Again overwriting the formula. I can share a sample spreadsheet if you need it.

This is the shared spreadsheet. Make a copy and you can then edit it. If the formulas do not work on your spreadsheet replace the "," with ";".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQI02kWgDfwsCr4WOmB2bE3fsspwt7cFqnHpqZysyOE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would be grateful if you did share the sample, i'm new to this and probably doing something wrong, cause i'm getting only formula parsing errors. =P

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but if i do not copy the formulae in the I and J columns in a blank cell first i'll get parse error. I created a new sheet using your sample as references and no problem at all. Guess i'll dig more into that. Thanks for your time and help =D